# Data binding WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hello I am new to WPF and I am not sure how to do the data binding and the code behind to get my textbox and button to be enabled and disabled.

If you could show me how to get it to work in the example below it would help me out in my project.

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBoxA"                  
          Margin="5"  
          SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBoxA_SelectionChanged"  >
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="Auto" Margin="5" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option1" Width="72"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option2" Width="72" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Option3" Width="72" />
</ComboBox>

<TextBox Name="TextBoxA"
         Margin="5" 
         Width="200"   
         IsEnabled="{Binding TextBoxEnabled}" />

<Button Name="ButtonA"
        Content="Next" 
        HorizontalAlignment="left"                
        Margin="5"                 
        IsEnabled="{Binding ButtonEnabled} />
```

C#

```
private void ComboBoxA_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBoxA = new TextBox();
    ButtonA = new Button();

    if (ComboBoxAfterProcessing.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {                    
        TextBoxA.IsEnabled = false;                    
        ButtonA.IsEnabled = false;
    }
    else if (ComboBoxAfterProcessing.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {                   
        TextBoxA.IsEnabled = true;
        ButtonA.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else if (ComboBoxAfterProcessing.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        TextBoxA.IsEnabled = true;
        ButtonA.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://wpftutorial.net/DataBindingOverview.html  Found by googling "[databinding wpf tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=databinding+wpf+tutorial&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=)"

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx you should rather go through the msdn which explains DataBinding in detail and with simple examples

Comment: as David suggests go through a few tutorials. With your code posted you are going around the binding by using 'code behind'. Data binding requires setting the data context of the user control's controls parent or similar. If your view model sends the correct IPropertyNotify notifications the control will change. Also Kobe's answer below is another way to achieve binding without code behind setting directly on the control instance.

Comment: I have read the pages above sadly I still can not get it to work in my example. I tried including INotifyPropertyChanged to "public partial class AddNewEvent : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged" and followed its implementation but failed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Write a class as follows which shall look like below

   ```
   public class ViewMole:INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
   public ViewMole()
   {
       ListValues = new List<string>() { "Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", 
                                          "Option5" };
   }
   public ICommand Click
   {
       get
       {
           return new RelayCommand();
       }
   }
   public List<string> ListValues
   {
       get;
       set;
   }
   string a;
   public string A
   {
       get
       {
           return a;
       }
       set
       {
           a = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("A");
       }
   }
   int index=0;
   public int SelectedIndex
   {
       get
       {
           return index;
       }
       set
       {
           index = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIndex");
           A = ListValues[index];
           if (index == 0)
           {
               IsEnabled = false;
           }
           else
           {
               IsEnabled = true;
           }
       }
   }
   bool isEnabled;
   public bool IsEnabled
   {
       get
       {
           return isEnabled;
       }
       set
       {
           isEnabled = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
       }
   }
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)
       {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Write another class which implements ICommand as below. This is to handel button click events

```
     public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Button cliked");
    }
}
```

Change your Xaml below

```
    <ComboBox Name="ComboBoxA"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding ListValues}"/>

    <TextBox Name="TextBoxA"  Margin="5"    Width="200"   Text="{Binding A}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>

    <Button Name="ButtonA"   Content="Next"   HorizontalAlignment="left" Margin="5"    Command="{Binding Click}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
```

In Xmal.cs set the data Context as beolw

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewMole();

    }
```

Refer the below links to understand why INotifyPropertyChanged and ICommand has to be used
http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx

Comment: Thank for showing me how to implement the example and the links are of benefit to me I will read those over.

Answer (score 0):

you can binding your textbox and button's IsEnabe Property to the Combox's  SelectedIndex 
Property and you neednot response to   ComboBoxA_SelectionChanged Event. in order to let the 
SelectedIndex  change your button and textBox's IsEnabe  you need a convetor in your binding
for example: